# import rsa private key and encrypt string

Tags: python, encryption, rsa

Trying to import a 2048 bit RSA private key that was created with openssl and use it to encrypt a string.  Following this https://cryptobook.nakov.com/asymmetric-key-ciphers/rsa-encrypt-decrypt-examples

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP

pr_key = RSA.import_key(open('my_priv_key.pem', 'r').read())

msg = "blah"

encryptor = PKCS1_OAEP.new(pr_key)

encrypted = encryptor.encrypt(msg)
print(encrypted)
```

error:

```
» python encrypt.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "encrypt", line 10, in <module>
    encrypted = encryptor.encrypt(msg)
  File "/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/PKCS1_OAEP.py", line 121, in encrypt
    db = lHash + ps + b'\x01' + _copy_bytes(None, None, message)
TypeError: can't concat str to bytes
```

Comment: this should work `msg = b"blah"`

Comment: same error with that

Answer (score 0):

That's because the encrypt method expects bytes as arguments. Using `msg = b'blah'` should do the trick, as well as changing the encrypt call to `encrypted = encryptor.encrypt(msg.encode('utf-8'))`

Comment: How did you generate this `my_priv_key.pem`?

Comment: via openssl e.g `openssl genrsa -out mykey.pem 2048`

Comment: It's funny because I got it working. Check [this example](https://repl.it/repls/AchingArtisticRefactoring)

Comment: hmm your code does not work for me (python 3.7.3)... very weird.

Comment: Yup, got it working with python 3.7.3 using docker as well. What's the version of `pycryptodome` that you're using? `pycryptodome==3.9.8` here

Comment: pycryptodome==3.9.8

Comment: Are you using docker? Which version of linux? Trying to find anything that's different in your installation compared to mine.

Comment: i'm on a mac, running python from a venv

Comment: ran the same code on a linux box and it worked fine... no idea why my mac won't run it

Comment: And it seems something specific of your machine. I've tried this code on macOS 10.15 with python 3.7.3 and everything ran smoothly.